# Adding and calculating User Input Fields in ArcGIS Modelbuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, network-analyst, calculate-values, closest-facility

I have a model which results in a list of routes with mileages.  I want to add 6 fields to the mileage table (Freight Rate, Freight Cost, Material Amount, Material Rate, Material Cost, and Total Price).  I want these 6 fields to be parameters that the user inputs prior to starting the model. The output of the table after the model with the field additions would look like below.
[image: Output after Model Completion]

I've tried adding six fields with 6 add fields but I can't add numbers to a field name.  Calculate value is a possibility but I can't understand how to do that.
[image: Current Model]

Comment: Why would you want to add numbers to the field names?  The fields names in your example screenshot do not have numbers.

Comment: You’re right. I didn’t explain that too well. I want to add the fields but then be able to populate the added fields from the interface before running the model

Answer (score 1):

I added add field and calculate field.  I used inline variables for the calculate field.  When the field is added it goes into calculate field and the inline variable populates the calculate field. The output resulted in a price per location.
[image: Model Interface]
[image: Model]
[image: Attribute Table Output]

Comment: It is my answer.